# How do I Cythonize a Python Enum mixin class?

Tags: python, cython

I have a Enum mixin (serde_enum.py) type that adds dump/load methods to the Enum for serialization/deserialization, that looks something like this:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Primitive:

    def load(self):
        pass

    def dump(self):
        pass
```

I can create an Enum `Apple` like so that has the extra `load()` and `dump()` methods:

```py
In [1]: import serde_enum                                                                                                        

In [2]: from enum import Enum                                                                                                    

In [3]: Apple = Enum('Apple', ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE'], type=serde_enum.Primitive)                                               

In [4]: Apple.__members__                                                                                                        
Out[4]: 
mappingproxy({'RED': <Apple.RED: 1>,
              'GREEN': <Apple.GREEN: 2>,
              'BLUE': <Apple.BLUE: 3>})

In [5]: Apple.RED.dump                                                                                                           
Out[5]: <bound method Primitive.dump of <Apple.RED: 1>>

In [6]: r = Apple(1)
```

Now, if I try to cythonize the mixin class (to speed up the slow load/dump code), it breaks the enum.  Here is my cython code (serde_enum.pyx):

```py
# cython: language_level=3
from enum import Enum

cdef class Primitive:

    cpdef load(self):
        pass

    cpdef dump(self):
        pass


class SerDeEnum(Primitive, Enum):
    pass
```

but now:

```py
In [1]: from enum import Enum                                                                                                    

In [2]: import serde_enum                                                                                                        

In [3]: Apple = Enum('Apple', ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE'], type=serde_enum.Primitive)                                               

In [4]: Apple.__members__                                                                                                        
Out[4]: 
mappingproxy({'RED': <Apple.RED: <serde_enum.Primitive object at 0x7ff91adc2ea0>>,
              'GREEN': <Apple.GREEN: <serde_enum.Primitive object at 0x7ff91adc2eb0>>,
              'BLUE': <Apple.BLUE: <serde_enum.Primitive object at 0x7ff91adc2ec0>>})

In [5]: Apple.RED.dump                                                                                                           
Out[5]: <function Apple.dump>

In [6]: r = Apple(1)                                                                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-670cfcdec304> in <module>
----> 1 r = Apple(1)

/usr/lib/python3.6/enum.py in __call__(cls, value, names, module, qualname, type, start)
    291         """
    292         if names is None:  # simple value lookup
--> 293             return cls.__new__(cls, value)
    294         # otherwise, functional API: we're creating a new Enum type
    295         return cls._create_(value, names, module=module, qualname=qualname, type=type, start=start)

/usr/lib/python3.6/enum.py in __new__(cls, value)
    533                     return member
    534         # still not found -- try _missing_ hook
--> 535         return cls._missing_(value)
    536 
    537     def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):

/usr/lib/python3.6/enum.py in _missing_(cls, value)
    546     @classmethod
    547     def _missing_(cls, value):
--> 548         raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
    549 
    550     def __repr__(self):

ValueError: 1 is not a valid Apple
```

The same thing happens if I create the enum with the mixin class by inheritance using the `SerDeEnum` class I defined above, like `Apple = serde_enum.SerDeEnum('Apple', ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE'])`

Comment: There's no value in this. Functions defined in Cython in non-cdef classes are still compiled (so will get sped if, if you do it right). Your `cdef class` doesn't have any members so there's no benefit at all to declaring it `cdef`.

Comment: That misses the point, but I can change the pyx so that dump/load are cpdef.. The same thing still occurs

Comment: `cpdef` is irrelevant too. That only gives you a quicker calling mechanism when you call the functions from Cython (which it doesn't look like you're doing). A `def` function in a normal class (no `cdef`) is still compiled by Cython. You can still specify types and get a speed-up.

Comment: The calling mechanism speedup is indeed important in the real code.  This is just toy code meant to demonstrate the issue, so I didn't bother to provide implementations of load and dump (to avoid getting hung up in implementation details like this).  The general question is, can a cythoned class be used as an Enum type mixin.  Semantically it seems there is no reason why not, but there is a behavioral difference.

Comment: cdef classes have different behaviour on construction (things like `__new__` and `__init__`), don't have a dictionary by default (although classes derived from them should do) and classes defined in C do have restrictions on inheritance. There's definitely a lot that can go wrong here

Comment: Do you really need to optimize the calling mechanism? Or is it enough to optimize the implementation of load/dump? In the latter case Primitive should be a plain Python class and the implementations can call some optimized cdef functions.

Comment: I don't think this is a Cython bug - I think the `enum` module is doing something odd. It works out that `type` has a custom `__new__`, not `object.__new__` and [sets `use_args` to `True`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8b914d2767acba3a9e78f1dacdc2d61dbfd7e304/Lib/enum.py#L207). This means that `._value_` is set to `Primitive(1)` rather than `1`. I don't know what you should do about though, but I suspect primitive should accept and store the argument

Comment: @UriBarkai optimizing load/dump will certainly help, but the way this module is implemented currently, Enum is just one type of Element--the load/dump reads/builds a buffer basically by calling load/dump recursively from the upper-most element down to the most basic primitive type, so there is a lot of time spent in python function call overhead

Comment: @Ugtar Have you looked at a [Cython `cpdef enum`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#c-variable-and-type-definitions)? It isn't quite the same as the `enum` module, but is similar. If your next level up is a `cdef class` then it can be stored very efficiently (and you'd probably put the load/dump at that level, rather than the enum level). I don't know if it's quite what you want, but it might be easier...

Comment: @DavidW thanks, i missed your last response. I'll definitely take a look